# Why won't my outdoor patio propane heater light?

Tags: patio, heater

No propane is coming out and we did replace the valve from the tank.

Any idea why it will not light?

Comment: Are you sure your tank has any propane left? Perhaps your gauge is broken.

Comment: The tank was a new one and full. Gas won't flow . Replaced the hose tank valve

Comment: cant figure out what may be plugged up ?